# bigquery aggregate for daily basis

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I have a table in big-query (datawarehouse):

[image]

and I would like to have the result of:

[image]

Here is the explanation on how the calculation should be:

1. 2017-10-01 = $100 is obvious, because the data is only one
2. 2017-10-02 = $400 is a sum of the first row and third row. Why? Because second row and third row have the same invoice. So we only use the latest update.
3. 2017-10-04 = $800 is a sum of row 1,3, and 4. Why? It is because we only take one invoice only per day. row 1 (T001), row 3(T002), row 4(T003)
4. 2017-10-05 = $100 is a sum of row 1,5, and 6. Why? It is because we only take one invoice only per day. row 1 (T001), row 5(T002), row 6(T003)

I honestly have completely lost how to do that. I have tried multiple times to group by and etc. But none of them work as expected. This is my latest effort so far for today:

```
SELECT 
  amount,
  updatedDateOnly,
  invNo
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    invNo,
    UpdatedDate,
    amount,
    DATE(updatedDate) as updatedDateOnly,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY  invNo ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC) AS rownum
  FROM [project:dataset.test] 
)
WHERE
  rownum = 1
```

only returns the last date. Now, I have no idea how to query for daily basis.

Appreciate for anyone who is expert and willing to help in querying. Thank you.

UPDATE:
Data in json, in case you want to try in bigquery or other SQL servers:

```
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-01 01:00:00","InvNo":"T001","amount":100}
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-02 01:00:00","InvNo":"T002","amount":200}
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-02 02:00:00","InvNo":"T002","amount":300}
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-04 01:00:00","InvNo":"T003","amount":400}
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-05 01:00:00","InvNo":"T002","amount":500}
{"UpdatedDate":"2017-10-05 02:00:00","InvNo":"T003","amount":500}
```

Comment: Your logic for taking sums is not completely clear to me.  Are you in general taking 1 plus N Plus N+1?

Comment: logic is still totally unclear. you should at least explain #3 and #4 also (as you did for #1 and #2)

Comment: ok. I got it - i mean logic of calculating

Comment: Basically, I want to sum total amount per day for each invoice number. Each invoice can be updated by users as many as they want daily so we should only take the latest one.

Comment: that's exactly how i got it - see my answer :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(UpdatedDate) UpdatedDay
  FROM `project.dataset.test`
),
qualified AS (
  SELECT DATE(UpdatedDate) UpdatedDay, InvNo, ARRAY_AGG(amount ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] amount
  FROM `project.dataset.test`
  GROUP BY UpdatedDay, InvNo
)
SELECT UpdatedDay, SUM(amount) amount
FROM (
  SELECT d.UpdatedDay UpdatedDay, InvNo, ARRAY_AGG(amount ORDER BY q.UpdatedDay DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] amount
  FROM dates d
  JOIN qualified q
  ON q.UpdatedDay <= d.UpdatedDay
  GROUP BY UpdatedDay, InvNo
)
GROUP BY UpdatedDay
-- ORDER BY UpdatedDay
```

You can test / play with this with below dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.test` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-01 01:00:00' UpdatedDate, 'T001' InvNo, 100 amount UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-02 01:00:00', 'T002', 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-02 02:00:00', 'T002', 300 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-04 01:00:00', 'T003', 400 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-05 01:00:00', 'T002', 500 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-05 02:00:00', 'T003', 500 
),
dates AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE(UpdatedDate) UpdatedDay
  FROM `project.dataset.test`
),
qualified AS (
  SELECT DATE(UpdatedDate) UpdatedDay, InvNo, ARRAY_AGG(amount ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] amount
  FROM `project.dataset.test`
  GROUP BY UpdatedDay, InvNo
)
SELECT UpdatedDay, SUM(amount) amount
FROM (
  SELECT d.UpdatedDay UpdatedDay, InvNo, ARRAY_AGG(amount ORDER BY q.UpdatedDay DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] amount
  FROM dates d
  JOIN qualified q
  ON q.UpdatedDay <= d.UpdatedDay
  GROUP BY UpdatedDay, InvNo
)
GROUP BY UpdatedDay
ORDER BY UpdatedDay
```

Result is as expected

```sql
UpdatedDay  amount   
2017-10-01   100     
2017-10-02   400     
2017-10-04   800     
2017-10-05  1100
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Now, I just need to apply this to my real data.

Answer (score 1):

On each date, you need the most recent amount for each invoice.  That is rather complicated.  One solution is to start with a cross join of the dates and your records.  Then window functions can be used to get the most recent amounts:

```
select dte,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then amount else 0 end) as amount
from (select d.dte, t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.invNo order by t.UpdatedDate desc) as seqnum
      from (select distinct date(UpdatedDate) as dte
            from `project.dataset.test` t
           ) d join
           `project.dataset.test` t
           on date(t.UpdatedDate) <= d.dte
     ) td
group by dte;
```