# Bigquery aggregrate the backlog value from daily days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like so:

```
 ID      | Date                        | Language
    ----------------------------------------------
    A    | 2020-06-09 07:00:00.342 UTC | EN
    A    | 2020-06-09 17:15:00.342 UTC | EN
    A    | 2020-07-16 23:11:37.342 UTC | EN
    A    | 2020-07-16 17:11:37.342 UTC | SN

    B    | 2020-06-09 17:11:37.342 UTC | SN
    B    | 2020-06-09 17:11:37.342 UTC | EN
    B    | 2020-07-16 17:11:37.342 UTC | SN
    B    | 2020-07-16 17:11:37.342 UTC | EN
    .... (and many more dates for other ID)
```

My query aim is the **current data for each day should be summation from the historical data for each ID**. So far, my query is able to sum the total of language for each day, but I am not sure how to edit the query so that it will add the data from backlogs as well, instead of data just for that particular day. Trying to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781209/bigquery-aggregate-for-daily-basis) (as my question is quite similar to this question , except that the question was asking to only take the latest ID, but I'm considering all ID), but quite confused as my current query is having subquery.

My work so far (only managed to calculate value per day without aggregration):

```
    WITH
    table1 AS (
    SELECT  
     ID ,Date, 
     SUM(CASE WHEN time >= '06:00:00' AND time <= '11:59:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS morning,
     SUM(CASE WHEN time >= '00:00:00' AND time <= '05:59:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS night,
     FROM (
         SELECT   
          ID , TIME_TRUNC(TIME(Timestamp), SECOND) AS time,  DATE(Timestamp) as Date, Language
         FROM 
            t
         GROUP BY ID, Language,  DATE(Timestamp) 
    )
GROUP BY  ID, Date
    ),
    
    table2 AS (
    SELECT  
      ID, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_EN,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sum_SN
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE(Timestamp) as Date,   ID, 
          CASE 
          WHEN Preferred_ Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN'  ELSE Language 
          END AS Language,
        FROM 
          t 
        GROUP BY ID, Language, 
    )
GROUP BY    ID,   Date

    ))
    SELECT   *
    FROM   table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table2 USING (ID)
```

Sample output:

```
   ID    | Date       | Sum_EN | Sum_SN 
    ------------------------------------
    A    | 2020-06-09 |   2    |   0
    A    | 2020-07-16 |   3    |   1
   
    B    | 2020-06-09 |   1    |   1
    B    | 2020-07-16 |   2    |   2
    .... (and many more dates for other ID)
```

Aggregration Logic:

1. For ID A, on **2020-06-09**, the total of EN language is 2 (noted that in a day, has >1 ID because time are varies), meanwhile on **2020-07-16** , the total of EN is 3 because it takes the value from previous days as well.
2. The same logic concept are for all days and IDs, so basically data value in new days are the **summations** of data value from all the *backlogs*.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using:

```
SUM(rating_total) OVER(
    PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(Date) 
  ) n_rating,
```

Answer (score 1):

The query that you want is more like this:

```
select id, date(date), 
       countif(lang = 'EN') as en,
       countif(lang = 'SN') as sn,
       sum(countif(lang = 'EN')) over (partition by id order by min(date)) as en_running,
       sum(countif(lang = 'SN')) over (partition by id order by min(date)) as sn_running
from t
group by id, date(date);
```

I'm not sure about the other conditions you have in your query.  You don't describe them in the question.